# Dodgy install/uninstall Puppet

Tags: uninstall, puppet, puppetmaster

Getting started with Puppet and also not much chop on Ubuntu. Seems I've made a mess of installing/uninstalling Puppet on Tahr. My hunch so far is that I've deleted it incorrectly and now my re-install is not working how I think it should.... Can anyone give a few tips to find what I'm missing?

---

Trying to run Puppet

`phil@phil-HP-xw8600-Workstation:~$ puppet
The program 'puppet' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install puppet-common`

I've gone through and installed it though -

`phil@phil-HP-xw8600-Workstation:~$ sudo apt-get install puppet-common
[sudo] password for phil: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
puppet-common is already the newest version.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 40 not to upgrade.`

### Whereis

I tried to uninstall Puppet manually by deleting what I could see of it files. Thing is originally it used to show up a bunch of places but now it is only there in a few spots:

*Before*
`whereis puppet
/etc/puppet 
/usr/bin/puppet
/usr/local/bin/puppet 
/usr/share/puppet 
/usr/share/man/man8/puppet.8.gz
/usr/bin/X11/puppet`

*After*
`phil@phil-HP-xw8600-Workstation:~$ whereis puppet
puppet: /usr/share/man/man8/puppet.8.gz`

Also done:

- `apt-get --purge remove puppet` [Purged] the install, re-did the install (see above)
- Installed via Software Center

Trying to purge the install after all this: 
`phil@phil-HP-xw8600-Workstation:~$ sudo apt-get --purge remove puppet
[sudo] password for phil: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Package 'puppet' is not installed, so not removed
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 40 not to upgrade.`

Answer (score 1):

The exact cause might be something slightly different but perhaps I just missed the ruby gem for puppet (puppet seems to utilize ruby a fair bit (which I don't have much knowledge on). I  executed the following command: 
`gem install puppet`

And then can see the locations for `puppet` as:

`whereis ruby
ruby: /usr/bin/ruby /usr/lib/ruby /usr/bin/X11/ruby /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz`

And after that showed up, calling `puppet` from the terminal appears differently:
`phil@phil-HP-xw8600-Workstation:~$ puppet
See 'puppet help' for help on available puppet subcommands`